# Pyspark - TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable while using OneHotEncoder in Spark MLlib

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am new to pyspark and Apache Spark machine learning library.
I am trying to apply OneHotEncoder for several categorical columns in Spark MLlib.
First I used stringIndexer, it works.

categoricalColumns is list of my categorical columns in dataset.

```
stringIndexer = StringIndexer(
    inputCols=[categoricalCol for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns],
    outputCols=[categoricalCol + "_index" for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns]
)
mod_si = stringIndexer.fit(spark_df)
indexed_si = mod_si.transform(spark_df)
indexed_si.printSchema()
```

Next OneHotEncoder

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(
    inputCols=[indexer.getOutputCol() for indexer in indexed_si],
    outputCols=["_encoded".format(indexer.getOutputCol()) for indexer in indexed_si]
)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

I read the programming guide but I couldn't solve it yet.Any help is appreciated.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder

Thank you

Comment: try indexed_si.columns